# How can I position a figure in Latex?

Tags: latex

I want to have the picture exactly in a specific position in my text. I use the commands below

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item T.D. Lee(1957 Physics Nobel Laureate)
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{TdLee.eps}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I have many figures like this. What happens is that I see figures and items in different order. Can you let me know which latex command i should use in order to have the picture under or right to the each item?

Thanks

Kurt

Comment: You should post this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10):

To work with the standard float system, you might try the h positioner (as mentioned in another answer) but with the ! modifier as in

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  ...
\end{figure}
```

There is even another H positioner, like h! but tries harder. It needs the package `float`

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{figure}[H]
  ...
\end{figure}
```

but even that doesn't work many times. However since you are doing this in a list, trying to use a float might not be the best for you.

You might try to create a [minipage](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_43.html) to house the figure. Or perhaps the way to do what you want might be to omit the `figure` environment all together but keep the `center` one if you want it.

Answer (score 7):

If you know exactly where you want the figure, don't use a float (that's what the "figure" environment is)...floats are there to.....wait for it.....*float*!

So if you know exactly where you want your figure, simply use `\includegraphics`:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item T.D. Lee(1957 Physics Nobel Laureate)
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{TdLee.eps}
\end{center}
...
\end{enumerate}
```

You can also redefine the `enumerate` environment so that you do not have to surround each picture with a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment, but if you are interested in how to do that, I'll leave it for a separate question. (And unapologetically suggest that you ask it on  the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.)

Comment: yeah, I guess I "buried the lead" on mine. I addressed the OP the way the question was asked first, then the better way second. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, everyone repeat together: "the figure environment has nothing to do with graphics!"

Answer (score 4):

Try the `h` placement specifier. From [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions):

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{TdLee.eps}
\end{figure}
```

It does not *guarantee* perfect placement, but it tries.